# Old Windows Wallpaper Image 'shedinfield1024' - Can anyone tell me where this photo was taken?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

[image]
This is a photograph of an old farm building in a valley amongst wooded mountains.  In the distance the roof of a white house with a red tile roof is visible.

Comment: “Old” Windows wallpaper made me think of Clouds.bmp...

Answer (score 22):

This pic seems to be originally taken by [Jay Torborg](http://www.jaytorborg.com/). You can find it the ["Alaska" album ("Photography" -> "Old Gallery")](http://www.jaytorborg.com/alaska.htm). It was taken somewhere around Juneau, Alaska. In [this reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/alaska/comments/18md6f/i_was_told_this_classic_windows_wallpaper_shed_in/c8gcut7/), user duanlian commented:

> taken about 10 miles north of Juneau near the Ace Hardware, with Thunder Mountain in the background.

Since it was taken 1999, scenery may have changed substantially. I wasn't able to identify the location using Google Maps.

Bing Sat images are quite detailed. The area mentioned above may be [around 58,369848, -134,604141](https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=9b109a6d-f318-4fd8-84c9-d25455ab9b16&cp=58.369151~-134.612595&lvl=15&style=h&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Allegedly, it was taken along Glacier road, somewhere around here: https://www.google.com/maps/@58.3718332,-134.6137676,3a,75y,51.61h,67.62t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sKMwijHeSiSbWdMIcua7NGg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. What does your answer add to the already existing answer?

Comment: That's in fact the only shed i was able to detect in that area, too. The mossy part of the roof suggests that the original pic is in fact looking from west to east. But i think the shed that's shown on GSV isn't the same as on the wallpaper (thus i refrained from posting it), since it lacks essential features. Especially, i would still expect the tree (or at least remnants of it) southeast of it, and there's no trace of that peculiar rhombic window.

Comment: @Mast It shows the shed, potentially.

Comment: The comments in the reddit thread indicate that the position of the looked for shed is some meters to the south of the shed visible on GSV. I suppose it's now "inside" the area of spruce trees directly between the shed visible on GSV and Glacier Highway. Alas, none of the available sat images show any details there, so no final proof...